# is there's a way for replace asp validators' face?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, validation

By default, `validators` of asp.net look like `label`. Can I replace them to become divs, `radiobox`, `checkbox` etc.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look at ASP.NET's Control Adapters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx

You will need to completely re-implement the rendering of the control, however, and the best way to do this is by going through the ASP.NET source-code or by using Reflector to see how it's done.